# Is a bounded linear operator $L$ from a Hilbert space $U$ to a Hilbert space $H$ continuous from $U$ to $LU$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let

- $U,H$ be $\mathbb R$-Hilbert spaces
- $L$ be a bounded linear operator from $U$ to $H$
- $LU$ be equipped with $$\langle u,v\rangle_{LU}:=\langle L^{-1}u,L^{-1}v\rangle_U\;\;\;\text{for }u,v\in LU\;,$$ where $L^{-1}:=\left(\left.L\right|_{\left(\ker Q\right)^\perp}\right)^{-1}$ denotes the pseudo inverse of $L$ (Note that $LU$ is a Hilbert space and $L^{-1}$ is an isometry from $LU$ to $U$)

> How can we show that $L$ is continuous from $U$ to $LU$?

Let $u\in U$. Since $U=\ker L\oplus(\ker L)^\perp$, there are $u_0\in\ker L$ and $v\in(\ker L)^\perp$ with $$u=u_0+v$$ and hence $$\left\|Lu\right\|_{LU}=\left\|L^{-1}(Lu)\right\|_U=\left\|L^{-1}(Lv)\right\|_U=\left\|v\right\|_U\tag1\;.$$ If $L$ would be continuous, we would have $\left\|Lu\right\|_{LU}\le\left\|u\right\|_U$ and hence $$\left\|v\right\|_U\le\left\|u\right\|_U\tag2$$ by $(1)$.

> $(2)$ seems to be wrong. I've found the claim in a lecture note. Are we able to  prove it or is the claim wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement $(2)$ is correct. Since $v \perp u_0$, the Pythagorean identity gives:

$$\|v\|_U^2 \le \|v\|_U^2 + \|u_0\|_U^2 =  \|v+u_0\|_U^2 = \|u\|_U^2$$

So $\|v\|_U \le \|u\|_U$.

Therefore, $$\|Lu\|_{LU} = \|v\|_U \le \|u\|_U$$

so $L$ is bounded and $\|L\| \le 1$. We conclude that $L$ is continuous.

Comment: I know that $L^{-1}$ is continuous from $LU$ to $U$. That's trivial, as you mention. You've misread the question. I've asked for the continuity of $L$ (not $L^{-1}$) from $U$ to $LU$.

Comment: @0xbadf00d Ah, I see. Well, an inverse of an isometry is also an isometry so it is continuous by the same argument.

Comment: But unless $L$ is injective, $(L^{-1})^{-1}\ne L$; at least if I'm not terribly wrong. $(L^{-1})^{-1}$ is defined only on $(\ker L)^\perp$. (And doesn't the proof of "the inverse of an isometry is an isometry" make use of surjectivity of the considered operator? Many people define an isometry to be surjective. But $L^{-1}$ is not surjective; unless $L$ is injective)

Comment: @0xbadf00d You are right. See the edit.